# ¿Por qué mi constante medianaTop10Chile devuelve NaN?

Tags: javascript

Este código tiene como objetivo calcular la mediana tanto general como del 10% de los salarios en chile. Pero la constante del diez por ciento (que corresponde a los sueldos más altos): medianaTop10Chile devuelve NaN.

```
const Chile = [];

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Ana',
salario: 400000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Alejandro',
salario: 12000000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Jade',
salario: 800000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Amelie',
salario: 1000000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Denisse',
salario: 500000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Nellie',
salario: 4000000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Blair',
salario: 400000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Lauren',
salario: 350000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Willow',
salario: 800000 
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Ash',
salario:  800000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Grace',
salario: 250000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Michell',
salario: 450000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Kara',
salario: 850000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Juniper',
salario: 600000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'presidente',
salario: 10000000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Emma',
salario: 800000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Lily',
salario: 850000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Harmony',
salario: 550000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Daniel',
salario: 600000
});
```

### //Helpers

Estas funciones hacen el proceso de validar si una cantidad de numeros es par o impar y de calcular la media aritmetica que necesitaremos en otras lineas de código.

```
function esPar(numero){
if( numero % 2 ===0){
   return true;
}else{
   return false;
}
}

function calcularMediaAritmetica(lista){

   const sumaLista = lista.reduce(
       function(valorAcumulado = 0, nuevoElemnto){
       return valorAcumulado + nuevoElemnto;
       }
       );
    
    const promedioLista = sumaLista / lista.length;
    return promedioLista;
    }
```

### //Análisis

### //Calculadora de mediana general

Aquí se calcula la mediana

```
    function medianaGeneralSalarios(lista){
    const mitad = parseInt(lista.length / 2); 

    if(esPar(lista.length)){

    const personitaMitad1 = lista[mitad - 1];
    const personitaMitad2 = lista[mitad];

    const mediana  = calcularMediaAritmetica([personitaMitad1, 
    personitaMitad2]);
    return mediana;


    }else{ //si la lista es impar 
    const personitaMitad = lista[mitad];
    return personitaMitad;
    }


    }
```

### Mediana general de los salarios

Aquí aislamos los salarios de las personas para devolverlos en un nuevo arreglo. Luego en la constante salarioChileOrdenado los ordenamos de menor a mayor. El objetivo de este bloque de código es calcular la mediana General de los salarios en Chile

```
    const salariosChile = Chile.map( 
    function (personita){
    return personita.salario;
    }
    );  

    const salarioChileOrdenado = salariosChile.sort(
    function (salarioA, salarioB){
    return salarioA - salarioB;
    }
    );

    const medianaGeneralChile = 
    medianaGeneralSalarios(salarioChileOrdenado);
```

### //Mediana del top 10%

Aquí calculamos la mediana del 10% de los salarios en Chile.

```
   const spliceStart = (salarioChileOrdenado.length * 90) / 100; 
   const spliceCount = salarioChileOrdenado - spliceStart;

   const salariosChiletop10 = salarioChileOrdenado.splice(
   spliceStart,
   spliceCount
   );
   const medianaTop10Chile = 
   medianaGeneralSalarios(salariosChiletop10);

   console.log({
   medianaGeneralChile,
   medianaTop10Chile
   });
```

Comment: Tendrías que editar tu pregunta y poner el resto del código, si no sabemos lo que hace la funcion medianaGeneralSalarios, es imposible ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Sencillo. El cálculo de los parámetros para segmentar el arreglo estaba mal hecho. Esa división no daba un entero Y, lo más grave, estabas restándole un entero **al arreglo ordenado**, cosa que no tiene mucho sentido si lo piensas.

Entonces, es sólo corregir las lineas

```
const spliceStart = parseInt((salarioChileOrdenado.length * 90) / 100); 
 const spliceCount = salarioChileOrdenado.length - spliceStart;
```

Corrigiendo eso, creo que funciona

```js
const Chile = [];

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Ana',
salario: 400000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Alejandro',
salario: 12000000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Jade',
salario: 800000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Amelie',
salario: 1000000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Denisse',
salario: 500000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Nellie',
salario: 4000000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Blair',
salario: 400000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Lauren',
salario: 350000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Willow',
salario: 800000 
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Ash',
salario:  800000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Grace',
salario: 250000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Michell',
salario: 450000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Kara',
salario: 850000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Juniper',
salario: 600000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'presidente',
salario: 10000000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Emma',
salario: 800000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Lily',
salario: 850000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Harmony',
salario: 550000
});

Chile.push({
nombre: 'Daniel',
salario: 600000
});

function esPar(numero){
if( numero % 2 ===0){
   return true;
}else{
   return false;
}
}

function calcularMediaAritmetica(lista){

   const sumaLista = lista.reduce(
       function(valorAcumulado = 0, nuevoElemnto){
       return valorAcumulado + nuevoElemnto;
       }
   );
    
   const promedioLista = sumaLista / lista.length;
   return promedioLista;
}
    
    
function medianaGeneralSalarios(lista){
    const mitad = parseInt(lista.length / 2); 

    if(esPar(lista.length)){

    const personitaMitad1 = lista[mitad - 1];
    const personitaMitad2 = lista[mitad];

    const mediana  = calcularMediaAritmetica([personitaMitad1, 
    personitaMitad2]);
    return mediana;


    }else{ //si la lista es impar 
    const personitaMitad = lista[mitad];
    return personitaMitad;
    }


}

    
  const salariosChile = Chile.map( 
  function (personita){
  return personita.salario;
  }
  );  

  const salarioChileOrdenado = salariosChile.sort(
  function (salarioA, salarioB){
  return salarioA - salarioB;
  }
  );

  const medianaGeneralChile = 
  medianaGeneralSalarios(salarioChileOrdenado);


 const spliceStart = parseInt((salarioChileOrdenado.length * 90) / 100); 
 const spliceCount = salarioChileOrdenado.length - spliceStart;

 const salariosChiletop10 = salarioChileOrdenado.splice(
 spliceStart,
 spliceCount
 );

 console.log(spliceStart, spliceCount);

 const medianaTop10Chile = 
 medianaGeneralSalarios(salariosChiletop10);

 console.log({
 medianaGeneralChile,
 medianaTop10Chile
 });
```